# iOS file download

Tags: attachment, mobile, ios

I need to download a binary file on the iOS for given `CombinedAttachments` objects. How can I do this? I tried to generate some links, but I was only able to download the `JavaScript` script file that redirects to the file in the browser. But I need a direct download link for the binary data.

I tried this so far:

```
let req = RestRequest.customEndPointRequest(with: .GET, endPoint: "sfc/servlet.shepherd/document/download", path: combinedAttachmentID, queryParams: nil)
```

Comment: You have to do a REST callout to ContentVersion object to get the VersionData. Once you get the blob data, you can use the native IoS functionalities to make them download.

Comment: That was it, thank you :)